# Grouping a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation, analytic-functions

I have three columns within my table:
`Amount`, `OrderNumber`, `Customerid`

For each `customerid` there will be `ordernumber` and `amount`.
Now i need to display `customerid`,`Ordernumber` and `Amount`(*total Amount- for each customerid*).

```
custid  srcnumber   amount
112     4344        20
112     7678        10
112     8766        30
34      6577        15
34      4566        5
```

Expected:

```
custid  srcnumber   amount
112     4344        60
112     7678        60
112     8766        60
34      6577        20
34      4566        20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum() over (partition by ..)` analytic function to sum up the amount per each row :

```
 select Customerid as custid,
        OrderNumber as srcnumber,
        sum(amount) over ( partition by Customerid ) as amount
   from tab
  order by custid desc
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0971aeffab05f6b24726e56628f1ac4)</kbd>